# How to get a collection of all direct child nodes of a node?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

In C# you can query an `XmlNode` to find its childs nodes using `SelectNodes()` API call and passing an `XPath`.

What is the `XPath` to get a collection of direct child nodes?

e.g.,

```
<actions>
    <if operation="A"> 
       <if operation="B">
            <store>some value</store>
            <if operation="C"> .... </if>
       </if>
    </if>
    <store>value</store>
</actions>
```

In the above example, i need to get the direct child of `<actions>` - nodes: `<if operation="A">` and `<store>`.
Due to the recursive nature of the XML, every `if` node can hold another List of `if`'s.

I tried `actionNode.SelectNodes("child::*")` but it gives me the whole tree of nodes below `<action>` (assuming `actionNode` points to the `<action>` XML).

Comment: If you want to get all child elements just use ````myXmlNode.ChildNodes```` collection. ````SelectNodes()```` is useful if you want only some of the child or subchild nodes. In that case you declare your selector expression via xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node direct children are available through node's `ChildNodes` property. See how to use it below.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod3()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(
        @"<actions>
            <if operation=""A""> 
                <if operation=""B"">
                    <store>some value</store>
                    <if operation=""C""> .... </if>
                </if>
            </if>
            <store>value</store>
            </actions>
    ");

    var actionsNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("/actions");

    // all direct child nodes are available through node.ChildNodes property
    var directChildren = actionsNode.ChildNodes;

    // here is the proof:
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(
        new string[] { "if", "store" }, 
        directChildren.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(i => i.Name).ToArray());
}
```